# How to create separate buttons with separate functions on TableViews in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm new to Xcode and Swift but am trying to teach myself as much as possible. My question is, concerning TableViews and separate cells. Each cell represents a different 'player' and I would like to be able to upgrade a single player at a time. I have tried to overcome this, but nothing seems to be working quite right.

Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



var beeslevel: [Int] {
    return [beelevel, wasplevel, bumblebeelevel]
}
var beelevel = 0
var wasplevel = 0
var bumblebeelevel = 0
let bees = ["bee", "wasp", "bumblebee"]


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return(bees.count)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell


    cell.beeimage.image = UIImage(named: bees[indexPath.row] + ".png")
    cell.beelabel.text = bees[indexPath.row]
    cell.beelevel.text = "\(beeslevel[indexPath.row])"

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
    tableView.endUpdates()


    return(cell)
}

@IBAction func beelevelup(_ sender: Any) {
    beelevelup()
}


func beelevelup() {
    beelevel += 1
    score -= 50
}
```

It's probably messy, and I'm sure I need to delete/rewrite a lot.

Comment: `beelevel` and `score` are properties of every single player?, why you don´t define a class with this attributes, and pass his objects types to your cells, if you want to I c an help you

Comment: @reiner Well technically, they aren't players. Instead, they are objects you can upgrade to receive more money in the game per second. Idk if this changes what you're saying, But I really need some help!

Comment: what is bees? you are showing a collection of bees, but every single bee have beeLevel and score?, can you define a bee class?

Comment: @ReinierMelian would I define a class for every bee?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Bees basically give you money when you're not tapping the screen. The more you have or the more you upgrade, the more money you get. However, I think using a tableview would be the best bet when displaying them, but I've come across a lot of difficulties